# Вывод данных из бд на django 3.0

Tags: html, база-данных, django

Добрый вечер у меня есть приложение motiv с бд и мне нужно вывести данные на стр шаблона, но почему-то когда я пишу блок for ... forend это место вообще не отображается. Подскажите что делать. Заранее спасибо Python/Django 3.0

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from . models import Motiv


def motiv(request):
    motiv = Motiv.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
    return render(request, "firstapp/motiv.html", {'motiv':motiv})


def Motiv_Detail(request, article_id):
    try:
        m = Motiv.objects.get( id = motiv_id )
    
    except:
         raise Http404("Статья не найдена!!!")

    return render(request, 'firstapp/detail.html', {'motivation':m})
```

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core import serializers


class Motiv(models.Model):
    motiv_title = models.CharField('Название поста', max_length = 120)
    motiv_text = models.TextField('Текст поста')
    views = models.IntegerField('Просмотры', default=0)
    img = models.ImageField(null = True, blank=True, upload_to='Motiv', help_text='150x150px', verbose_name='Изображение')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.motiv_title

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 7))
        
    class Meta:
                verbose_name = 'Мотивация'
                verbose_name_plural = 'Мотивация'
                ordering = ["-id"]
```

urls.py (в приложение)

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


app_name = 'motiv'
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/motiv/', views.motiv, name='motiv'),
    path('home/motiv/<int:motiv_id>/<int:img_id>/', views.Motiv_Detail, name='Motiv_Detail'),
]
```

motiv.html

```html
{% block content %}
        <div class="high-title-text" id="font-face">
            <p>Our Motivation</p>
        </div>
        <!------------ CONTENT  -------------->
        {% if motiv %}
            {% for a in motiv %}
                <div class="motiv-content">
                    <p>{{ a.pub_date }}</p>
                    <a href=""><p>{{ a.motiv_title }}</p></a>
                    <a href=""><img class="motiv-img-content" src="{{ a.img.url }}"></a>
                    <div class="motiv-content-text">
                        <a href="{% url 'motiv:list' %}"><p>{{ a.motiv_text }}</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            Статьи не найдены =(
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
import os, sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'firstapp'))


SECRET_KEY = 'Shalom'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles',
    'learn',
    'motiv',
    
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hello.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hello.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

[image]

Comment: Добавь полное содержимое  файла motiv.html. На результат в данном случае не влияет, но все таки, плохая практика внутри функции(`motiv`) переопределять переменную с таким же именем.

Answer (score 0):

На вашем месте я бы переписал `views`:

```
def motiv(request):
    motiv = Motiv.objects.all()
    return render(request, "firstapp/motiv.html", {'motiv':motiv})
```

потом `html`

```
{% block content %}
        <div class="high-title-text" id="font-face">
            <p>Our Motivation</p>
        </div>
        <!------------ CONTENT  -------------->
        {% if motiv.motiv_title %}
            {% for a in motiv %}
                <div class="motiv-content">
                    <p>{{ a.pub_date }}</p>
                    <a href=""><p>{{ a.motiv_title }}</p></a>
                    <a href=""><img class="motiv-img-content" src="{{ a.img.url }}"></a>
                    <div class="motiv-content-text">
                        <a href="{% url 'motiv:list' %}"><p>{{ a.motiv_text }}</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            Статьи не найдены =(
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Надеюсь это помогло!

Comment: Спасибо но нет. Все также

Comment: а ты создал эти статьи через админку?

Comment: да у меня есть 2 статьи

Comment: у меня всего 3 apps, 1 articles там все работает 2 и 3 нет, но я делаю все также как и в 1 app, может в setting.py что-то?

Comment: В db я смотрел через mysql lite там показывает 2 статьи id 1; id 2 так что с бд все норм

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в {% if motiv.motiv_title %} , а надо {% if motiv %}